# Expand UL LI with limit of LI

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML output;

```
<div id="list">
<ul>
 <li>Test 1</li>
 <li>Test 2.</li>
 <li>Test 3</li>
 <li>Test 4</li>
 <li>Test 5</li>
 <li>Test 6</li>
 <li>Test 7</li>
 <li>Test 8</li>
 <li>Test 9</li>
 <li>Test 10</li>
 <li>Test 11</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

What I need to do, is display the same HTML, but with a button to expand by 3 on 3 or 4 on 4

I use this script to just show and hide

```
$('#list ul li:gt(3)').hide();
$('.show_button').click(function() {
    $('#list ul li:gt(3)').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

So, lets say i have 10 LI, on page load just show 3, if i click the button expand to 6, one more click expand to 9....

thanks for any help

Comment: How this question is related to ajax?

Comment: mistake... sorry i will remove the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#list ul li:gt(2)').hide();
$('.show_button').click(function() {
    $('#list ul li:hidden:lt(3)').slideToggle();

    if( ! $('#list ul li').is(':hidden') )
        $(this).hide();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: THanks works fine, i just dont understand why show 4 LI's on the start and this says 3 $('#list ul li:gt(3)').hide(); but works good.. if you have time and you know how i can like hidden button when no more LI's to expand.thanks.

Comment: @alvaro Fixed that, see updated answer. `gt()` uses a 0-based index, so hiding greater than 3 actually shows the first 4; simply switch to `gt(2)` instead. Also added button hiding when there are no more `<li>`s to show

Comment: Do you know how i can hidden the .show_button when no more li to show? and thanks, works great.

Answer (score 0):

To increment it three at a time, you'll need to create some sort of a counter. I created a varaible called count, since it is a 0-based index, we begin counting at 2 (the third item). Each time you click, it increases the counter by three and reveals the new results. Here's the jsFiddle of the result: http://jsfiddle.net/qPBxs/

```
count = 2;
$('#list ul li:gt('+count+')').hide();
$('.show_button').live('click',function() {
    $('#list ul li:gt('+count+')').slideDown();
    $('#list ul li:gt('+(count + 3)+')').hide();
    count = count + 3;
    return false;
});​
```